# What laws cover patented DNA in humans in relation to the patent owner?

Tags: united-states, intellectual-property, patents, civil-rights

Some conspiracy theorists make the absurd claim that if patented DNA ends up in your genome, then you become a *patented* GMO, and thus the patent owner has some degree of legal control over you and/or your offspring.  Of course the [13th Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) bans slavery and involuntary servitude, but are there any other laws covering this sort of thing?  For example, if your body contained DNA patented by Acme Genetics, I'm sure that Acme couldn't charge you a fee every time you had a child, but is that because there are laws which are applicable in that scenario, or is it because no judge would ever rule that way despite the absence of any laws?

Comment: Now if your DNA was *copyrighted* by Acme Genetics, on the other hand...